# Why do my dygraph axis labels default to a smaller font?

Tags: r, plot, fonts, axis-labels, dygraphs

The font for my axes labels in dygraph plots remains small no matter what I've tried.

If I simply load up the dygraph package and plot the included sample data:

```
library("dygraphs")
lungDeaths <- cbind(mdeaths, fdeaths)
dygraph(lungDeaths)
```

I get the following result, where the font for the x and y axis tick labels is very small:

[Font on x and y axis tick labels too small](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jNeY.png)

What I would expect is the following plot where the font and size of the axis labels matches the axis titles and legend font:

[Plot with correct axis tick label font size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2O8ld.png)

I have tried setting dyAxis options such as axisLabelFontSize, axisLabelFormatter, and also tried some css code such as:

```
.dygraph-axis-label-x { -moz-transform: font-size: 20px; }
```

all with no luck. Why would my default axis label text not match the rest of the dygraph plot? Is there something in my system settings that overrides the dygraph options?

Comment: you shouldn't use Rstudio's viewer to judge the final ouput, take a look at it in a web browser -it looked fine to me... If you want to toggle options on the plot, I suggest creating the graph using lattice, base r, or ggplot2

Comment: Ah, you are right, thanks! The font size is consistent when I save it as html. It seems to default to a small Times Roman font though, so I'll have to try to change that still. The various dyOptions don't seem to have any effect so far. What do you mean by toggle options? I didn't think ggplot2 allows for the same interactive features?

Comment: by toggle options i simply meant that changing and formatting plots is easier with a dedicated plotting package -you're right that ggplot2 doesnt have  interactive options but if you wrap the `ggplot` call in the `ggplotly()` command (from plotly package) then itll produce an output very similar to the one you posted -or conversely you can plot it directly with `plotly()`